# How can I stop a JavaScript from executing if an element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Firefox addon that injects/executes a jQuery script on every page at sub.example.com. The script doesn't work on one page of the site, because of bad design. Is there any way to stop the script from being executed if a certain element is located on the page?

EDIT: The script I am using has to be executed **before** the DOM loads. Is there any way to access the HTML file itself and find out if the element exists?

Comment: you should read about jquery `on` api and see if you could use that in your page..

Comment: OK, the answers below both answer the question, they just don't solve my problem. I managed to find a workaround by specifying a URL exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since jQuery collections are just beefed up arrays, they each have a `length` property, which tells you how many elements it has matched:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    if ( $('#someElement').length ) return;
    // All of your code should go here...
});
```

Comment: I recommend `if ( $('#someElement')[0] )` for conciseness, since that expression either evaluates to a DOM reference or `undefined`, which is exactly what has to be checked.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - IMHO `.length` is clearer at what it does: it checks the length of the collection. Either way is good though...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, I assume your script is wrapped in a `$(document).ready` callback, if so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#breakOnThisElem').length) {
       return;
    }
});
```

If your code isn't wrapped in a function like this: change it! :)

Comment: Please, explain the downvote. I don't mind Down-voters, as long as they explain the reason. I might learn a thing or 2

Comment: The OP clearly stated that they *don't* want to run their code if that element existed (I wasn't the downvoter though).

Comment: Not my DV, but `.ready()` isn't useful on individual elements. It'll work, but will run when the DOM is ready just like a typical ready call. In other words, `.ready()` ignores the selector.

Comment: @JosephSilber: My initial answer does just that: it's exactly the same as yours... The second part was added after the DV, but is incorrect, I'll remove it.

Comment: Yours and his return on opposite conditions. Yours would be correct if you had the page code inside the `if` instead of a `return` statement.

Comment: @JosephSilber: aw, nips... how many times can you overlook something like that... Sorry for that

Comment: Two questions (I'm not used to using `if`): what does `return` mean, and what is `$(document).ready`?

Comment: `$(document).ready` is a jQuery event, basicallye, it means: if the document (the HTML) is fully loaded, then execute the `$(document).ready(function(){//this code, the callback});` This prevents code from being executed before the DOM is loaded. If, for example `$('#someId')` selects an element, but the element isn't loaded yet, your code would fail, that's why you should use `$(document).ready`. `Return` on its own returns `undefined`, and stops the function from doing anything else. Everything after the return statement will be ignored

Comment: @Ian: (part II) The return statement will only be executed `if` that element (`$('#someSelector')`) is found in the DOM. When you say _you're not used to using `if`_, might I ask what you use instead? I mean, if and else is pretty basic...

Comment: @Elias: I don't often have a use for `if` because I use JavaScript/jQuery for changing the DOM only; I don't usually use it for funcionality.

Comment: @Ian: 0_o ---- stunned... Just a friendly, but strong, suggestion: start learning the basics of branching, loops and functions. If you don't use `if`'s and `else`'s your code will be _very_ brittle: `$('#nonExistantElement').css({...});` breaks your code, a simple if would prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was actually looking for a way to prevent that.

Comment: @Munawir, You appear to have edited this 5 year old post to **only** change it from one type of indenting style to another. We **do not** edit posts to just change indenting style from one valid style to another. In addition, you should avoid editing *old posts* just to change indenting or other small, minor issues. Go ahead and make changes where something important is wrong (e.g. a word that would normally be searched for is misspelled, but don't edit just to correct the spelling of a non-critical word), If you do edit a post fix all the problems that exist, not just some of them.